# What is the proper way of handling multiple JSON Objects with Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, pojo

I am trying to parse a JSON URL with Retrofit 2 for my Android project and I have a question. In my URL the JSON look like this:

```
{  
"channel0":{  
  "song":"Crush",
  "artist":"Jennifer Paige",
  "duration":"180",
  "playedat":"1545065265",
  "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/8eecc92227fcbb09b43472f000df74e1.png"
},
"channel1":{  
  "song":"Reasons Why",
  "artist":"Brand New Immortals",
  "duration":"180",
  "playedat":"1545065371",
  "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/c059afda95dd35354af26cf72e5deab4.png"
},
"channel2":{  
  "song":"Dance Me To The End Of Love",
  "artist":"Leonard Cohen",
  "duration":"300",
  "playedat":"1545065181",
  "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/a368617dc7dc4716a9badb523ff6e7d4.png"
},
"channel3":{  
  "song":"4 Minutes",
  "artist":"Madonna",
  "duration":"180",
  "playedat":"1545065300",
  "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/1dcefc6496be4155a00f919dcbb54f77.png"
},
"channel4":{  
  "song":"Mothers, Sisters, Daughters",
  "artist":"Voxtrot",
  "duration":"180",
  "playedat":"1545065257",
  "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/5861b97231bd4ffe9218dfcacc27d68a.png"
}
}
```

And when I use POJO, it creates multiple classes for every channel. So what is the proper way of handling this JSON URL?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a fault of the API.  They should return a channels array, have an ID on the channel object, and remove the variable keyname.  There are ways to handle it, but reformating the response is IMO the "proper" way.

Comment: Code on this site should be written out. This makes it easier for us to help you debug.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Any text, including code, errors or JSON, needs to go in your question *as text*, not screenshots.

Comment: @meagar Changed it to text.

Answer (score 3):

Every JSON object can *also* be considered a `Map` of strings to JSON elements. In cases like this, where you're going to get an object with dynamic key names, you don't have to try to build a Java class to represent it. You can just use `Map<String, Object>` instead.

In this case, you know that each value will be a song, so you can be a little more specific than `Object`.

Start by defining e.g. a `Song` class to hold the inner elements:

```
public class Song {

    public String song;
    public String artist;
    ...
}
```

And then you'd make your call and loop over the result:

```
Call<Map<String, Song>> call = ...
call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, Song>>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Map<String, Song>> response) {
        Map<String, Song> body = response.body();
        for (Song song : body.values()) {
            // your code here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

You can even turn it into a list of songs if you need to for some reason:

```
List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>(body.values());
```

Comment: When I use the line 'retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call =restInterface.getChannels();' I get incompatible types error and it turns to 'retrofit2.Call<List<Channel>> call =restInterface.getChannels();' as auto solution by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

First: this is not called JSON URL... it's simple JSON, or JSON data if you want... URL and JSON are two totally separated things

Second: is not clear what you mean when you say:

> And when I use POJO, it creates multiple classes for every channel. So
>   what is the proper way of handling this JSON URL?

If you are generating Java classes from any JSON to POJO tool this is a normal behavior since no tool has how to guess that `channel2` is the same thing as `channel3` as JSON instances they can be two totally different things, there is no way to know.

The right way is to design your Java classes first and then map the JSON, not the opposite.

Comment: All caps is totally unnecessary.